# How to use xpath to find all of a nodename?

Tags: xpath

I saw the "XML perspective" option, in the Eclipse Mars, and there is the "XPath expression" view. I'm reading about in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) and trying to use it. But when I type the name of a node, it will show "empty expression" (expressão vazia - in portuguese) and no matches:

[image]

Am I using it wrong?

**--update**

Using `//` also didn't work:

[image]

Comment: Please do not add code (the XPath expression, in this case) in images, but as text. You probably know this anyway, given your reputation. If you ask an XPath question, please include the XML document you are searching. Finally, explain what you are looking for in this document. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MathiasMüller sorry, it's a private code. But the question is about the syntax of XPath, for any code.

Comment: Any code can be modified to remove sensitive information. There is no "syntax of XPath, for any code", XPath expressions only make sense in the context of a specific document. I can only repreat myself: Please do not add code in images, but as text. Please include the XML document you are searching. Finally, explain what you are looking for in this document.

Answer (score 4):

`xpath` is a path. So you can't just type a name of a node. It's relative to the current position.

But you can prefix it with `//` to denote 'anywhere in document'.  E.g. `//div` or `.//div` for anywhere in the current branch. (Which will be the same if current branch is root)

Comment: Also didn't work. I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You're working on namespaced XML nodes. `<h:panelGroup` is a `panelGroup` node from a namespace aliased with `h`. `//h` does not find anything because there is no node `h` in your document.

Without knowing how your XPath expression evaluator works with namespaced nodes, I cannot help any further. But most often you need to register the XML namespace and its alias. If that has been done, you could look for

```
//h:panelGroup
```

given that you registered `h` as an alias for the namespace used in the original document.

And evening your `div` example I assume that there is a default namespace defined in the document for HTML nodes.